# TensorFlow Bazel build failing

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm building TensorFlow with Bazel using `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer` as instructed to by the TensorFlow ['installing from sources' instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: /home/ubuntu/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD:5:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor:stream_e
xecutor' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command third_party/gpus/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool
_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fPIE -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-fr
ee-nonheap-object ... (remaining 87 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exite
d with status 1.   

tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc: In function 'cudnnConvolutionFwdAlgo_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::ToConvF
orwardAlgo(perftools::gputools::dnn::AlgorithmType)':                                                                              
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:269:10: error: 'CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT' was not declared in this scope         
     case CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT:  

...
```

Stack: EC2 g2.8xlarge machine running Ubuntu 14.04.2. Bazel version 0.1.5 (installed w/ `bazel-0.1.5-jdk7-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`).

I've tried Bazel 0.1.4 and 0.2.3 and I get the same error.

Comment: I recently encountered the same exact errors.  In my case, I was upgrading to TensorFlow 7.1 (from 6.0).  In the end, I wound up upgrading CUDA (from 7.0 to 7.5) and cuDNN (from v2 to v4) so that I didn't have to build from source.  (I was only building from source because TensorFlow 7.1 was expecting to find CUDA 7.5 and I only had 7.0.)  Anyway, I know that's not really an answer, but depending on what you're trying to accomplish, maybe a similar approach will work for you.

Comment: I just did the same thing. But I still would like to be able to build from source!

Comment: Did you try building from source after upgrading CUDA/cuDDN?  I figured the build failure was probably the result of some incompatibility with CUDA 7.0 or cuDNN pre-v4, but I didn't bother trying to build from source after upgrading.

Comment: Yep, I tried building after upgrading and I got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue building tensorflow in Ubuntu 16.04.

First of all ensure that you are using gcc version <= 4.8

In my case I had to install it doing:

For gcc

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
```

For g++

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 10
```

Once having the right version of gcc and g++, I had to edit the CROSSTOOL file as follows:

```
gedit tensorflow_sources_folder/third_party/gpus/crosstool/CROSSTOOL
```

Search every ocurrence of this specific line:

```
tool_path { name: "gcc" path: "clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc" }
```

And insert the following line exactly above it:

```
cxx_flag: "-D_FORCE_INLINES"
```

So the result must be:

```
cxx_flag: "-D_FORCE_INLINES"
tool_path { name: "gcc" path: "clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc" }
```

Comment: is gcc 4.8.4 too high? I get the same error with Ubuntu 14.04, Bazel 0.3.0, TensorFlow 0.8, aws g2.2xlarge