# Bazel build error with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am getting issue when I want build bazel with tf, I saw almost same issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830934/tensorflow-wont-build-with-cuda-support)

I am using NVIDIA GFORCE 1080, CUDA 8, cudnn 5.ubuntu 16.04

```
jesse@jesse-System-Product-Name:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
..........
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1039
        _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 976, in _create_local_cuda_repository
        _host_compiler_includes(repository_ctx, cc)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 145, in _host_compiler_includes
        get_cxx_inc_directories(repository_ctx, cc)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 120, in get_cxx_inc_directories
        set(includes_cpp)
depsets cannot contain mutable items
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1039
        _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 976, in _create_local_cuda_repository
        _host_compiler_includes(repository_ctx, cc)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 145, in _host_compiler_includes
        get_cxx_inc_directories(repository_ctx, cc)
    File "/home/jesse/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 120, in get_cxx_inc_directories
        set(includes_cpp)
depsets cannot contain mutable items
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.739s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/tools/pip_package
```

Comment: I figured it out 

It seems that I have a problem with Tensorflow branch, it should be up to date with this code `$ git checkout r1.0`

I solved it by the following points, after git clone tensorflow 

    $ cd tensorflow
    $ git checkout r1.0
    $ ./configure 
 
Then continue your other steps like 

    $ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 

Good luck

Comment: This is a new issue with tensorflow when building with bazel 0.5.3. e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11871. Should be fixed soon.